# twisted command line protocol

Tags: python, twisted

I have a `HistoricRecvLine` that I use as an interface to a `twisted.internet.protocol.ProcessProtocol` class. I can get information from the `HistoricRecvLine` to the protocol without problems but I cannot seem to find the magic binding to go the other way: aka I want information from the protocol to be displayed in the CLI. To be clearer, I want to have stdout/stderr messages of the sub process created by the ProcessProtocol appear in the my CLI implementation of the HistoricRecvLine.

Anyone knows how to do that or can point me to the right direction?

Comment: There isn't any magic.  Information flows either direction using the same mechanism: call methods with data.  Can you be more specific about what you're having trouble with?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: Question edited, does the make more sense?

Comment: Not really.  What's stopping you from calling a method on the protocol that handles your CLI from a method fon your `ProcessProtocol` that has the data you want displayed?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Because I cannot see *which* method to call!  The CLI and the ProcessProtocol are independent and passed to the `twisted.conch.insults.insults.ServerProtocol`. The CLI can see the protocol but not vis-ver-ca.

Comment: Why can't you make the protocol "see" the CLI?  `theProtocol.setCLI(theCLI)` should do it.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: Sorry, being dense here... Where is the API for this method?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: I think I got it (better late than never, right? ^_~) and I got something working.  Basically, in the constructor of the CLI, I am called a set_cli() method on all the sub-process protocols. However, this gives me a slight circular reference which I am uneasy with. Would creating deferred work better in this case or would it be over kill?

Comment: Deferreds aren't directly applicable to avoiding circular references.  Or at least I don't see an obvious way that I would apply them in this case to avoid them.  Fortunately Python comes equipped to handle circular references, so I don't think you should really worry about it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30160/discussion-between-jean-paul-calderone-and-sardathrion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jean Paul Calderone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18243/jean-paul-calderone) in his comments offered a hint to a solution.

The command line has a reference to the protocol.  In the protocol, create a method `set_cli_write_func(self, func)` that set the correct method for writing to the cli.  When you construct the cli, call the function on the appropriate protocol with something like:

```
def lpr(self, message): 
    """Print a message to the screen.

    :type message: String
    :param message: The message string.
    """
    self.terminal.nextLine()
    self.terminal.write(_format_message(message))
    self.terminal.nextLine()
    self.drawInputLine()
```

So that this method is called form the protocol.

Note that this creates a kind of circular dependency so you need to check for that when objects get destroyed.